# Gatsby itself changes the url on the page after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

My page in gatsby node

```
for (const browser of browsers) {
  for (const locale of locales) {
  actions.createPage({
    path: `/${browser}/${locale}`,
    component: path.resolve('./src/templates/Main.tsx'),
    context: {
      browser,
      locale,
      messages: await getMessages(locale),
      page: 'home',
    },
  })
```

On the server there is a logic that uses the request headers to give the necessary page and on the path / gives the necessary Main.tsx template the problem is that after loading the page path changes for example to /chrome/en/ with / How to disable this

I expecting issue for remove auto changing path